# Difference between 'emotional well-being' and 'mental health'

Tags: word-choice, difference

In this sentence, which one is better? 'emotional well-being' or 'mental health'?

> In the long term, I will establish an NGO to offer a variety of free
>    elementary level courses to promote students’ academic performance as
>    well as _____________ (**mental health** / **emotional well-being**).

Comment: It depends on which you mean. "Emotional well-being" is a pompous way of saying "happiness"; "mental health" is a pompous way of saying "sanity". A lunatic may be exuberantly happy, and a woman of unquestionable rationality and balance may be appallingly miserable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Well being** and **coping skills** have become the recent fashion to be offered by schools to help students through stressful times.  It is a nod to the life changing event that is **living on one's own** in a boarding situation without the usual **support systems** of family and friends that one may have grown used to having around.

Some *progressive* schools offer areas where dogs or cats that can be **borrowed** for an hour or taken on a walk. Others may offer **mediation**, **music therapy** or a formal **buddy** system where upper classmen look after **new students** to help them **learn the ropes**.

There are even courses that teach **learning how to learn**.

> In the long term, I **wish** to establish an **organization** offering a variety of **basic** skill courses to promote students’ academic performance as well as **emotional well-being**.

Would describe your long-term desire to aid both the **head** and the **heart** of students.

Comment: Would it be better if I use the word 'will' instead of 'wish' ? cuz the word 'wish', I think, may contain the meaning that 'this may not happen'; however, the word 'will' may sound more determined.

Comment: I would use "want to". "will" is OK but means you are certain it will happen.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on what the "courses" are.

Problems specifically caused by academic studies are more likely to relate to *emotional well-being*, finding a healthy balance between studies and other daily activities.
As I understand your phrase, I would use *emotional well-being*.

*mental health* more likely refers to more serious mental illnesses. Perhaps underlying conditions that are made worse by academic pressure. These more likely would be addressed by a psychologist.